# How large can PNG file be in kilobytes

Tags: image, png

How much can be the most complex PNG image in kilobytes, say, 100x100 pixels? How can I calculate it?

Comment: User ShuggyCoUk has given a pretty good answer to the [worst case file size for PNG](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=80628) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum numbers of bits per pixel in a PNG is 64, so 640,000 bits, or 80,000 bytes.

There'll also be an 8 byte signature in the beginning of the file, some other information about the file, and EXIF data can contain arbitrary amounts of information. [Wikipedia has information on the spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

If you're looking for a reasonable approximation for an upload limit, 100-150kb is probably fair. If you're looking for an exact number, there isn't one.

Comment: Why would that be? E.g. PNG-32 uses 8 bit per channel.